# Row_Number() continue in Union query

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

```
;WITH CTE AS
(
Select * From
        (
        SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY StatusDate) AS SrNo, FirstName
From Tab1
  UNION ALL
   SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY StatusDate) AS SrNo, FirstName
   From Tab2
) v
)
Select * From CTE
```

Is there anyway I could continue after the `Row_Number()` generated in Tab1. So if 1st result in `UNION` ended at 10000 the 2nd table in UNION should start from 10001

**Note:** I want the `Row_Number()` as it is inside the `Select * From`

Thus I don't can't change it to:

```
;WITH CTE AS
(
Select *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY StatusDate) AS SrNo From
        (
        SELECT FirstName
From Tab1
  UNION ALL
   SELECT FirstName
   From Tab2
) v
)
Select * From CTE
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: `UNION` includes a distinct. `ROW_NUMBER` prevents that distinct. move the row_number outside or use `UNION ALL`

Comment: Do you or do you now want to remove duplicates?

Comment: @Aツ: As I said I don't can't move Row_Number outside. That was a typo in the question. I have fixed it. It is UNION ALL now. I don't want the Row_Num to repeat. After using UNION ALL that is what is happening.

Comment: @GordonLinoff: I want that no duplicates should be there the ROw_Number() should begin from where 1st query in the UNION left off. So 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10 is what I desire. At the moment I get 1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,5

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since you're not partitioning the data the maximum row_number should be equal to the count of rows so you could simply add the count of rows in tab1 to the row number in tab2:

```
;WITH CTE AS
(
SELECT * FROM
        (
        SELECT 
          ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY StatusDate) AS SrNo, 
          FirstName 
       FROM Tab1
       UNION ALL
       SELECT 
          ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY StatusDate) + (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tab1) AS SrNo, 
          FirstName 
       FROM Tab2
       ) v
)
SELECT * FROM CTE
```

Comment: Looks extremely promising. Let me try :)

Answer (score 4):

Your requirements are not completely clear, but from what I can interpret, this is what I would do.

```
;WITH UnionedData AS
(
SELECT FirstName, StatusDate, 10 AS SortOrder
FROM Tab1
UNION
SELECT FirstName, StatusDate, 20 AS SortOrder
FROM Tab2
)
SELECT FirstName, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY SortOrder, StatusDate) AS SrNo
FROM UnionedData
```

Answer (score 1):

Let me guess that this is what you really want:

```
select FirstName
from tab1
union all
select FirstName
from tab2
where not exists (select 1 form tab1 t1 where t1.firstname = t2.firstname)
```

Then you can enumerate the results as:

```
select FirstName, row_number() over (order by which, StatusDate) as srNo
from ((select FirstName, StatusDate, 1 as which
       from tab1
      ) union all
      (select FirstName, StatusDate, 2 as which
       from tab2
       where not exists (select 1 form tab1 t1 where t1.firstname = t2.firstname)
      )
     ) f
```

Comment: Super. Are you computer? Looks a bit confusing to my mind but it works!